# Facebook Analytics Exporting data

Tags: facebook-analytics

My problem is that I would like to download the csv from a facebook analytics cohort. And the button in the top right corner does just that. But downloading many reports manually is a lot of work, so I would like to do it from a script. I know of the Facebook Analytics Export option via their API, but that is only for the events (if I understood correctly) and doesn't seem to work for me besides (2 requests have the status "SCHEDULED" for over a day now, and their documentation says the whole process of preparing the files is 1-2 hours). 
I have tried a simple web crawler but facebooks robots.txt forbids it from scraping any data.
Have I missed some API option that just lets me send which cohort and from which to which date I want data to be included, and would allow me to just perhaps get the data from a https request?

Thanks in advance!